# How to use alias in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have following query and i am getting perfect result what i want but i want to use stManufacturerPartReference alias in where clause condition Like following second query but it gives me error.

```
WITH ProductsCTE (inProductId, inCategoryId, stCategory, stManufacturers, inCompanyId, stERPId,stManufacturerPartReference,
                                stProductName, stProductNumber, stModel, stFileLink, stImage, dcPrice,dcStandardPrice, dcOnHandQty,dcQtyOnPO,dtEstimatedShipDate, dcWeight, inSyncStatus, dtLastSyncDate,
                                inErrorRetry,flgIsActive, flgIsDeleted, inCreatedBy, inModifiedBy, dtModificationDate, dtCreationDate, inRecordCount)
                AS (
                    SELECT
                        product.inProductId,
                        product.inCategoryId,
                        product.stCategory,
                        product.stManufacturers,
                        product.inCompanyId,
                        product.stERPId,
                        product.stProductName,
                        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PM.stManufacturerPartReference
                           FROM tblProductManufacturers PM
                           JOIN tblProducts Product on PM.inProductId = Product.inProductId
                           JOIN tblManufacturers M on M.inManufacturerId = PM.inManufacturerId
                           WHERE PM.inProductId=product.inProductId
                           ORDER BY M.stManufacturer
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as stManufacturerPartReference,
                        product.stProductNumber,
                        product.stModel,
                        product.stFileLink,
                        product.stImage,
                        product.dcPrice,
                        product.dcStandardPrice,
                        product.dcOnHandQty,
                        product.dcQtyOnPO,
                        product.dtEstimatedShipDate,
                        product.dcWeight,
                        product.inSyncStatus,
                        product.dtLastSyncDate,
                        product.inErrorRetry,
                        product.flgIsActive,
                        product.flgIsDeleted,
                        product.inCreatedBy,
                        product.inModifiedBy,
                        product.dtModificationDate,
                        product.dtCreationDate,
                        CAST((COUNT(product.inProductId) OVER()) AS BIGINT) AS inRecordCount
                    FROM tblProducts Product WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE 1=1
                    AND product.flgIsDeleted <> 1 
                    AND flgIsHistoricItem <> 1 AND (product.inCompanyId = 1)   )

    SELECT  P.inProductId,
            P.inCategoryId,
            P.stCategory,
            P.stManufacturers,
            P.stManufacturerPartReference,
            P.inCompanyId,
            P.stERPId,
            P.stProductName,
            P.stProductNumber,
            P.stModel,
            P.stFileLink,
            P.stImage,
            P.dcPrice,
            P.dcStandardPrice,
            P.dcOnHandQty,
            P.dcQtyOnPO,
            P.dtEstimatedShipDate,
            P.dcWeight,
            P.inSyncStatus,
            P.dtLastSyncDate,
            P.inErrorRetry,
            P.flgIsActive,
            P.flgIsDeleted,
            P.inCreatedBy,
            P.inModifiedBy,
            P.dtModificationDate,
            P.dtCreationDate,
            P.inRecordCount
    FROM ProductsCTE P
    ORDER BY stCategory ASC
    OFFSET (1 - 1) * 1000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

i want to use stManufacturerPartReference in Where Clause Like Following.

```
WITH ProductsCTE (inProductId, inCategoryId, stCategory, stManufacturers, inCompanyId, stERPId,stManufacturerPartReference,
                                stProductName, stProductNumber, stModel, stFileLink, stImage, dcPrice,dcStandardPrice, dcOnHandQty,dcQtyOnPO,dtEstimatedShipDate, dcWeight, inSyncStatus, dtLastSyncDate,
                                inErrorRetry,flgIsActive, flgIsDeleted, inCreatedBy, inModifiedBy, dtModificationDate, dtCreationDate, inRecordCount)
                AS (
                    SELECT
                        product.inProductId,
                        product.inCategoryId,
                        product.stCategory,
                        product.stManufacturers,
                        product.inCompanyId,
                        product.stERPId,
                        product.stProductName,
                        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PM.stManufacturerPartReference
                           FROM tblProductManufacturers PM
                           JOIN tblProducts Product on PM.inProductId = Product.inProductId
                           JOIN tblManufacturers M on M.inManufacturerId = PM.inManufacturerId
                           WHERE PM.inProductId=product.inProductId
                           ORDER BY M.stManufacturer
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as stManufacturerPartReference,
                        product.stProductNumber,
                        product.stModel,
                        product.stFileLink,
                        product.stImage,
                        product.dcPrice,
                        product.dcStandardPrice,
                        product.dcOnHandQty,
                        product.dcQtyOnPO,
                        product.dtEstimatedShipDate,
                        product.dcWeight,
                        product.inSyncStatus,
                        product.dtLastSyncDate,
                        product.inErrorRetry,
                        product.flgIsActive,
                        product.flgIsDeleted,
                        product.inCreatedBy,
                        product.inModifiedBy,
                        product.dtModificationDate,
                        product.dtCreationDate,
                        CAST((COUNT(product.inProductId) OVER()) AS BIGINT) AS inRecordCount
                    FROM tblProducts Product WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE 1=1
                    AND product.flgIsDeleted <> 1 
                    AND flgIsHistoricItem <> 1 AND (product.inCompanyId = 1) AND  stManufacturerPartReference LIKE '%ABC DEF%'  )

    SELECT  P.inProductId,
            P.inCategoryId,
            P.stCategory,
            P.stManufacturers,
            P.stManufacturerPartReference,
            P.inCompanyId,
            P.stERPId,
            P.stProductName,
            P.stProductNumber,
            P.stModel,
            P.stFileLink,
            P.stImage,
            P.dcPrice,
            P.dcStandardPrice,
            P.dcOnHandQty,
            P.dcQtyOnPO,
            P.dtEstimatedShipDate,
            P.dcWeight,
            P.inSyncStatus,
            P.dtLastSyncDate,
            P.inErrorRetry,
            P.flgIsActive,
            P.flgIsDeleted,
            P.inCreatedBy,
            P.inModifiedBy,
            P.dtModificationDate,
            P.dtCreationDate,
            P.inRecordCount
    FROM ProductsCTE P
    ORDER BY stCategory ASC
    OFFSET (1 - 1) * 1000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

But it Gives me Error "Invalid column name 'stManufacturerPartReference'."
So how can i use alias in where clause please help.
thanks.

Comment: You can't. Repeat the expression in the `WHERE` clause or wrap another `SELECT` around the other one.

Comment: You need to learn about the order of execution in a SQL query: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

WHERE comes immediately after FROM, and therefore any aliases are not available to filter on. As others have mentioned, you'll need to wrap your query in another statement/table variable/temp table etc. in order to filter on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do instead :

```
SELECT *, STUFF(stManufacturerPartReference, 1, 1, '') AS stManufacturerPartReference
FROM . . . . 
     . . . . CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT ', ' + PM.stManufacturerPartReference
       FROM tblProductManufacturers PM JOIN 
            tblProducts Product 
            ON PM.inProductId = Product.inProductId JOIN 
            tblManufacturers M 
            ON M.inManufacturerId = PM.inManufacturerId
       WHERE PM.inProductId=product.inProductId
       FOR XML PATH('') 
     ) tt(stManufacturerPartReference)
WHERE . . . AND
     stManufacturerPartReference LIKE '%ABC DEF%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the order of execution in a SQL query: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

WHERE comes immediately after FROM, and therefore any aliases are not available to filter on.

As it's wrapped in a CTE, filter on stManufacturerPartReference in the query after it.

```
WITH ProductsCTE (inProductId, inCategoryId, stCategory, stManufacturers, inCompanyId, stERPId,stManufacturerPartReference,
                                stProductName, stProductNumber, stModel, stFileLink, stImage, dcPrice,dcStandardPrice, dcOnHandQty,dcQtyOnPO,dtEstimatedShipDate, dcWeight, inSyncStatus, dtLastSyncDate,
                                inErrorRetry,flgIsActive, flgIsDeleted, inCreatedBy, inModifiedBy, dtModificationDate, dtCreationDate, inRecordCount)
                AS (
                    SELECT
                        product.inProductId,
                        product.inCategoryId,
                        product.stCategory,
                        product.stManufacturers,
                        product.inCompanyId,
                        product.stERPId,
                        product.stProductName,
                        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PM.stManufacturerPartReference
                           FROM tblProductManufacturers PM
                           JOIN tblProducts Product on PM.inProductId = Product.inProductId
                           JOIN tblManufacturers M on M.inManufacturerId = PM.inManufacturerId
                           WHERE PM.inProductId=product.inProductId
                           ORDER BY M.stManufacturer
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as stManufacturerPartReference,
                        product.stProductNumber,
                        product.stModel,
                        product.stFileLink,
                        product.stImage,
                        product.dcPrice,
                        product.dcStandardPrice,
                        product.dcOnHandQty,
                        product.dcQtyOnPO,
                        product.dtEstimatedShipDate,
                        product.dcWeight,
                        product.inSyncStatus,
                        product.dtLastSyncDate,
                        product.inErrorRetry,
                        product.flgIsActive,
                        product.flgIsDeleted,
                        product.inCreatedBy,
                        product.inModifiedBy,
                        product.dtModificationDate,
                        product.dtCreationDate,
                        CAST((COUNT(product.inProductId) OVER()) AS BIGINT) AS inRecordCount
                    FROM tblProducts Product WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE 1=1
                    AND product.flgIsDeleted  1 
                    AND flgIsHistoricItem  1 AND (product.inCompanyId = 1)   )

    SELECT  P.inProductId,
            P.inCategoryId,
            P.stCategory,
            P.stManufacturers,
            P.stManufacturerPartReference,
            P.inCompanyId,
            P.stERPId,
            P.stProductName,
            P.stProductNumber,
            P.stModel,
            P.stFileLink,
            P.stImage,
            P.dcPrice,
            P.dcStandardPrice,
            P.dcOnHandQty,
            P.dcQtyOnPO,
            P.dtEstimatedShipDate,
            P.dcWeight,
            P.inSyncStatus,
            P.dtLastSyncDate,
            P.inErrorRetry,
            P.flgIsActive,
            P.flgIsDeleted,
            P.inCreatedBy,
            P.inModifiedBy,
            P.dtModificationDate,
            P.dtCreationDate,
            P.inRecordCount
    FROM ProductsCTE P
    WHERE P.stManufacturerPartReference LIKE '%ABC DEF%'
    ORDER BY stCategory ASC
    OFFSET (1 - 1) * 1000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use outer apply or cross apply (select .. AS stManufacturerPartReference) and if your server is 2017 you could use String_AGG function to get list of values instead of for xml clause.